# Self-referential has_many and belongs_to relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to build a schema around the concept of a Company.

A Company can have a parent company (ie, a conglomerate).  A company can also have several child Companies.  But a Company can also be stand-alone, and have neither children Companies nor a parent company.  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to model this with ActiveRecord.  Here is what I have:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :company_id
    has_many :products
    has_many :subsidiaries, :class_name => "Company", optional: true
    belongs_to :parent_company, :class_name => "Company", optional: true
end
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to check `company.subsidiaries`, if it is nil, I know that that company has no child companies.

Any help figuring out the right way to build this relationship would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything that would prevent you from using the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)? It handles tree structures like this quite well and provides a large number of helper methods to navigate and manipulate the tree.

Comment: Nope, I think I can use that.  I've been reading through the docs and it seems as though this is a good solution, but I'm wondering whether there is a simple solution that doesn't use any additional gems.  For the time being, i am going to continue exploring your suggestion.

Comment: Did a quick search as I thought I had done this, but that old memory of mine! I used the acts_as_tree gem if this offers any help.

Comment: As Andrew Lank says, there's also acts_as_tree which used to be Rails core but was moved to a gem as part of an austerity movement. Using a version-locked gem is a safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

Think more along the lines of `has_many :through` It's a little bit more dynamic for this application http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/10/30/self-referential-has-many-through

**UPDATE**

I lied... misread... new edit in a second

**UPDATE ...AGAIN!**

Actually, I'm just overhtinking it. That blog should give a firm working example. Sorry, I'm working extra hours right now. Sleep deprivation will make you second-guess anything

Answer (score 0):

A quick look into the acts_as_tree gem source shows the relationships

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => name, :foreign_key => configuration[:foreign_key], :counter_cache => configuration[:counter_cache]
has_many :children, :class_name => name, :foreign_key => configuration[:foreign_key], :order => configuration[:order], :dependent => :destroy
```

where :foreign_key would be set to parent_id in your table. Just note however that you will have to implement the methods traversing which acts_as_tree gem offers for free. Hope this points you in some kind of direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
belongs_to :page, :inverse_of => :subpages
has_many :subpages, class_name: "Page",
                 foreign_key: "page_id", 
                 dependent: :destroy
```